# LinkModified event on MindFusion WPF diagram

Tags: wpf, notifications, diagram

I use WPF diagram component from MindFusion (MindFusion.Diagramming.Wpf.Diagram).

XAML:

```
...
<Grid>
   <diag:Diagram x:Name="diagram"/>
</Grid>
```

On the diagram instance I subscribe for link modifications (.LinkModified):

Code:

```
diagram.LinkModified += ViewModel.LinkModified;
```

As the documentation says now I get this event only when the user modifies the link.

My question is, if anyone has an idea how to get a notification if the link is modified without user interaction (e.g. diagram modifies link automatically after moving other element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the meantime i found the solution:

subscribe on

```
diagram.LinkRouted
```